# Proving that one of $a(1-b), b(1-c), c(1-a) \le \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

how can a prove that at least one of those is less than or equal to 1/4.
$$\forall a,b,c\in \mathbb R^+, \ a(1-b)\leq 1/4 \lor b(1-c) \leq 1/4 \lor c(1-a) \leq 1/4.$$
help please!

Comment: Suppose not and multiply.

Comment: What is the maximum value of $a(1-a)$? What about $b(1-b)$ and $c(1-c)$? Is this a contradiction?

Comment: Then regroup - and see a contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can assume $1-a, 1-b, 1-c \geq 0$, since otherwise we are done.

By the AM-GM inequality (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality), we have $abc(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) \leq (\frac{a+b+c+(1-a)+(1-b)+(1-c)}{6})^6= (\frac{1}{2})^6 = \frac{1}{64}$.

Then, if $a(1-b)> 1/4, b(1-c) > 1/4$ and $ c(1-a) > 1/4$, multiplying together we get $abc(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)> (\frac{1}{4})^3 = \frac{1}{64}$, which is a contradiction, and thus the result follows.

EDIT:

If you do not want to use AM-GM: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+ $. We have $0\leq (\sqrt x - \sqrt{(1-x)})^2 = x +(1-x) -2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$, and thus $ 2\sqrt{x(1-x)} \leq 1$, which implies $x(1-x) \leq \frac{1}{4}$. Apply this for $a,b$ and $c$, multiply together, and you get the inequality of the first paragraph.

Comment: What's wrong with AM-GM? It is one of the simplest inequalities out there.

Comment: You could find the maximum of $a(1-a)$ looking at it as a quadratic polynomial in $a$.

Comment: @user161440 I extended my answer with an approach avoiding AM-GM, studying the function x(1-x)

Comment: That's a good remark. I edited the answer: we can assume that, because otherwise, one of the three numbers we would like to be less than or equal to 1/4, would be negative, which is less than 1/4

Comment: how could you mutiply a(1-a)*b(1-b)*c(1-c) what rule is this? what if a(1-a) is negative??

Comment: If a is greater than 1, then $c(1-a)<0<1/4$ and we are done. If a is less than or equal to 1, the last paragraph of my answer applies.

Comment: Because that is how the argument works (I believe he is using the intermediate value theorem). But, just as in my proof, it does not matter, because if one of a,b,c is greater than 1, as I already said, then the problem is DONE.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use AM-GM you can do it this way.

Let's asume without loss of generalization that $a\leq b\leq c$.

Trivially, If $1 \leq c$ then $b(1-c) \leq 0 \leq 1/4$.

If $a\leq 1/2 \leq b$ or $b\leq 1/2 \leq c$ then $a(1-b)\leq 1/4$ or $b(1-c)\leq 1/4$. (respectively)

If $1/2 \leq a$ then let $a' = a-1/2$ and $b' = 1/2 - (1-b) = b - 1/2$ Note that $a' \leq b'$

Then $a(1-b) = (1/2 + a')(1/2 - b') = 1/4 - (b'-a')/2 -a'b' \leq 1/4$.

Similarly, if $c \leq 1/2$. Let $a' = 1/2 - a$ and $b' = (1-b) - 1/2 = 1/2 - b$. Note that this time, $a' \geq b'$.

Then $a(1-b) = (1/2 - a')(1/2 + b') = 1/4 - (a'-b')/2 -a'b' \leq 1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

First assume $a, b, c \lt 1$.

without loss of generality, assume $a \le b$

Now consider the quadratic

$$f(x) = x^2 - x + a(1-b)$$

$f(0) = a(1-b) \gt 0$

$f(b) = b^2 - b + a(1-b) = (a-b)(1-b) \le 0$

Thus the quadratic has a real root (ok, some calculus used, but [elementary proofs exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128898/inequality-acabc0-prove-b-c24aabc/128901#128901)), and thus the discriminant =$ 1 -4a(1-b) \ge 0 \implies a(1-b) \le \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Am I missing a triviality that expands this for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @DanZimm: If $c \ge 1$, then $b(1-c) \le 0$.

Comment: Ah yes, it was a triviality, thanks!

Comment: For $a,b,c \le 1$, see my comment to DanZimm. There is no need of $c$ if $a \le b$. There is an implicity renaming of variables going on. For instance if you chose $a=0.3, b = 0.1, c = 0.4$, we kind of have implicitly swapped $b$ and $c$ in our proof...