# Show that for all positive real numbers $a,b$, not both of $a(1-b),b(1-a)$ are greater than $\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Show that for all positive real numbers $a,b$, not both of $a(1-b),b(1-a)$ are greater than $\frac{1}{4}$

**Attempt**:
I have attempted several things with this problem. I will note what I feel is the most promising: note that $a(1-b)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $b(1-a)=\frac{1}{4}$ induces the following functions: 
$$y=1-\frac{1}{4x} \ \ \ and \ \ y=\frac{1}{4(1-x)}$$

As a side note, these functions are inverses. I noticed that these functions intersect at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and if we had chosen any value other than $\frac{1}{4}$ we would've ended up with more than one  or no intersections. So I thought let $c$ be a real positive number and suppose  $a(1-b),b(1-a)$ are both greater than $c$. Then the induced functions are: $$y=1-\frac{c}{x} \ \ \ and \ \ y=\frac{c}{1-x}.$$We have to show that the set $$\{x>0,y>0,y>1-\frac{c}{x},y>\frac{c}{1-x}\}$$ is empty when $c>\frac{1}{4}$. We note that the functions intersect at $$x=\frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4c})$$ which is clearly not real when $c>\frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871288)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose for some positive real numbers $a,b$ we have $a(1-b) > \dfrac{1}{4}$ and $b(1-a) > \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Then, $a(1-b) \cdot b(1-a) > \dfrac{1}{4} \cdot \dfrac{1}{4}$, which is equivalant to $a(1-a) \cdot b(1-b) > \dfrac{1}{4} \cdot \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Is this possible?

Comment: ahh the maximum of $a(1-a)$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ at $\frac{1}{2}$ so of course it can't be greater.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach is the following:

Note that we need to be concerned only with $0 \leq a,b \leq 1$.

Now, $a(1-b)b(1-a)=a(1-a)b(1-b)$. Can you find the maximum value of $x(1-x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{4}$!!!

Comment: @illysial: do you now see how that helps you to solve your question?

Comment: I am thinking that since $a(1-a)$ and $b(1-b)$ both have a maximum value of $\frac{1}{4}$ then, as @JimmyK4542 suggested, we cannot have their product exceeding $\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: @illysial: yes true.

Comment: This is amazing: I can't believe I didn't notice $a(1-b)b(1-a)=ab(1-b)(1-a)=b(1-b)a(1-a)$